# Smooth scrolling on a click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a smooth scrolling effect using javascript library react. I don't want to use JQuery.

I want to archive when user clicks on a link that he goes to appropriate section of the page.

My handleScroll function is as follows :

```
handleScroll(ref, offsets, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let offset = offsets[ref]; // this is where it needs to scroll for example 900
    let activeLinks = {};
    activeLinks[ref] = "active";
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    let time = 4000;
    let offsetTo = this.state.offsetTo; //offsetTo is 0 on page load
    let timer = setInterval(function() {
        let step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
        offsetTo = offsetTo + 40;
        if(offsetTo >= offset) {
            return;
        }
        window.scrollTo(0, offsetTo);
        if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
    },10);
    this.setState({activeLinks: activeLinks}, () => timer);
}
```

This works pretty fine but only if I'm top of the page. When I click on the link it goes to the appropriate section with an animation.

But when I then click on some other link it works, but it starts from the top and not from the place where I am.

I need to find a way to set the `offsetTo` to the appropriate value, and then depending on it to go to the top or to the bottom.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll should do the trick.

see the examples, it's pretty straight forward.